# Number of palindromic subsequences of length four

Tags: algorithm, palindrome, subsequence

Given a string `S` of length `n` containing only lowercase English letters, we are to calculate number of palindromic sub-sequences of length 4.

Total number of palindromic sub-sequences can be computed by `O(n^2) DP`.  But how to calculate the number of such subsequences for a length 4 in order `O(n log n)` or `O(n)`?

Example: "abcdbaadc" has answer 4. [indices (1, 2, 5, 6), (1, 2, 5, 7), (3, 6, 7, 9), (4, 6, 7, 8)]

Any hint or explanation is appreciated.

Comment: Total number of palindromic subsequences can be computed in O(n) too. See http://adilet.org/blog/25-09-14/

Answer (score 2):

Since the length is 4, you can enumerate all possible strings of length 4 of the form ABBA, and for every string, run a standard algorithm to find number of subsequences of that particular string in the given string.

Complexity: O(n*26*26), n is the length of the string. Below is the python code to find number of subsequences of a particular string in another string.

```
def num_subsequences(seq, sub):
m, n = len(seq)+1, len(sub)+1
table = [[0]*n for i in xrange(m)]
def count(iseq, isub):
    if not isub:
        return 1
    elif not iseq:
        return 0
    return (table[iseq-1][isub] +
           (table[iseq-1][isub-1] if seq[m-iseq-1] == sub[n-isub-1] else 0))
for row in xrange(m):
    for col in xrange(n):
        table[row][col] = count(row, col)
return table[m-1][n-1]
```

Comment: You make some assumptions in your analysis. Might be a good idea to state them.